# JS Tree - Select parent node when all the child nodes are selected

Tags: jstree, jstree-search

I am using JSTree. When you check a node, I want to see if its all sibling nodes are also selected, if yes, I want to select the parent node and deselect all the child nodes. How can I achieve this with JsTree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to tweak it to fit your situation but this should be basically what you need:

```
$(jsTreeSelector).on("select_node.jstree", function (node, selected) {
    var parentNode = $(jsTreeSelector).jstree(true).get_parent(selected.node.id);
    var siblingNodes = $(jsTreeSelector).jstree(true).get_children_dom(parentNode);
    var allChecked = true;
    $(siblingNodes).each(function () {
        if (!$(this).children('.jstree-anchor').hasClass('jstree-clicked')) allChecked = false;
    });
    if (allChecked) {
        $(siblingNodes).each(function () {
            $(jsTreeSelector).jstree(true).deselect_node(this);
        });
        $(jsTreeSelector).jstree(true).select_node(parentNode);
    }
});
```

Make sure three_state is set to false in your tree config